# How to get rid of fungus from toe nail damage?

Tags: pain, feet, home-remedies

A toe nail appears to have a fungus attack after damage during a accident and is experiencing pain.

After  taking some home remedies like applying Turmeric Powder onto it it seems better, but you want to cure it permanently. What are some remedies?

Answer (score 2):

Your best and most efficient method in "curing" this situation is to seek professional attention from a podiatrist or dermatologist (webmd.com).  Particularly if you are still experiencing some pain after time has passed from the original injury, along with the fungal reaction, this may be an indicator of a more serious underlying issue.

> > Your doctor may try one thing or a combination:
> >
> > ```
> >     A topical cream that goes directly on the nail
> >     An antifungal prescription pill
> >     Removing the damaged area of the nail or skin
> >
> > In some cases, you might need to have the nail removed completely with surgery.
> > ```
> >
> > http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/ss/slideshow-toenail-fungus

I previously had a toenail fungal infection and tried home remedies, mostly including some sort of hot water foot soak, especially as the infection had spread to the surrounding skin:

- white vinegar
- Isopropyl (rubbing) alcohol
- epsom salt
- baking soda

Ultimately, it was determined the entire nail had to be removed.  This procedure was performed at a Podiatrist's office with a local anesthetic injection, and I was walking out - pain free - 15 minutes later.  The new nail took some time to grow in ...but grew in healthy, straight, and blemish-free!  Thankfully it was covered by my medical insurance; even with the co-pay, it was well worth the price of admission!

Hope this is helpful!